# How to fix .Net SDK installation on CentOS?

Tags: .net, sdk, centos

I have followed instructions in a couple of places to install .Net SDKs on CentOS (Stream release 9).

[image]

Why is `dotnet --info` not showing installed SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to install from this [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual) i had no success.

Then i tried this:

`RUN  dnf install dotnet-sdk-7.0 -y`

after this, i ran `dotnet --info` with this output:

```
[root@ebf572389108 .dotnet]#  dnf install dotnet-sdk-7.0 -y
CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS                                                                                  5.8 MB/s | 8.4 MB     00:01    
CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream                                                                                12 MB/s |  15 MB     00:01    
CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages                                                                          16 kB/s |  12 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.
==========================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Architecture             Version                        Repository                  Size
==========================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 dotnet-sdk-7.0                                  aarch64                  7.0.105-2.el9                  appstream                   83 M
Installing dependencies:
 aspnetcore-runtime-7.0                          aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                  7.0 M
 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0                   aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                  1.6 M
 dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0                         aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                  3.6 M
 dotnet-host                                     aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                  196 k
 dotnet-hostfxr-7.0                              aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                  158 k
 dotnet-runtime-7.0                              aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                   22 M
 dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0                       aarch64                  7.0.5-2.el9                    appstream                  2.7 M
 dotnet-templates-7.0                            aarch64                  7.0.105-2.el9                  appstream                  2.7 M
 libicu                                          aarch64                  67.1-9.el9                     baseos                     9.5 M
 lttng-ust                                       aarch64                  2.12.0-6.el9                   appstream                  288 k
 netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1                  aarch64                  7.0.105-2.el9                  appstream                  1.3 M
 numactl-libs                                    aarch64                  2.0.14-7.el9                   baseos                      30 k
 userspace-rcu                                   aarch64                  0.12.1-6.el9                   baseos                     110 k

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================
Install  14 Packages

Total download size: 134 M
Installed size: 528 M
Downloading Packages:
(1/14): numactl-libs-2.0.14-7.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                             264 kB/s |  30 kB     00:00    
(2/14): userspace-rcu-0.12.1-6.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                            642 kB/s | 110 kB     00:00    
(3/14): aspnetcore-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                    8.7 MB/s | 7.0 MB     00:00    
(4/14): aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                             1.7 MB/s | 1.6 MB     00:00    
(5/14): dotnet-host-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                               2.9 MB/s | 196 kB     00:00    
(6/14): libicu-67.1-9.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                                     7.8 MB/s | 9.5 MB     00:01    
(7/14): dotnet-hostfxr-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                        2.7 MB/s | 158 kB     00:00    
(8/14): dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                   4.3 MB/s | 3.6 MB     00:00    
(9/14): dotnet-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                         21 MB/s |  22 MB     00:01    
(10/14): dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                4.8 MB/s | 2.7 MB     00:00    
(11/14): lttng-ust-2.12.0-6.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                               2.2 MB/s | 288 kB     00:00    
(12/14): netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                         2.4 MB/s | 1.3 MB     00:00    
(13/14): dotnet-templates-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                   2.2 MB/s | 2.7 MB     00:01    
(14/14): dotnet-sdk-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64.rpm                                                          20 MB/s |  83 MB     00:04    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                      21 MB/s | 134 MB     00:06     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                  1/1 
  Installing       : dotnet-host-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                                 1/14 
  Installing       : aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                               2/14 
  Installing       : dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                     3/14 
  Installing       : dotnet-hostfxr-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                          4/14 
  Installing       : dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                   5/14 
  Installing       : dotnet-templates-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                                      6/14 
  Installing       : netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                            7/14 
  Installing       : userspace-rcu-0.12.1-6.el9.aarch64                                                                              8/14 
  Installing       : numactl-libs-2.0.14-7.el9.aarch64                                                                               9/14 
  Installing       : lttng-ust-2.12.0-6.el9.aarch64                                                                                 10/14 
  Installing       : libicu-67.1-9.el9.aarch64                                                                                      11/14 
  Installing       : dotnet-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                         12/14 
  Installing       : aspnetcore-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                     13/14 
  Installing       : dotnet-sdk-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                                           14/14 
  Running scriptlet: dotnet-sdk-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                                           14/14 
  Verifying        : libicu-67.1-9.el9.aarch64                                                                                       1/14 
  Verifying        : numactl-libs-2.0.14-7.el9.aarch64                                                                               2/14 
  Verifying        : userspace-rcu-0.12.1-6.el9.aarch64                                                                              3/14 
  Verifying        : aspnetcore-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                      4/14 
  Verifying        : aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                               5/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                     6/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-host-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                                 7/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-hostfxr-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                          8/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                          9/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-sdk-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                                           10/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                                                  11/14 
  Verifying        : dotnet-templates-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                                     12/14 
  Verifying        : lttng-ust-2.12.0-6.el9.aarch64                                                                                 13/14 
  Verifying        : netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                                                           14/14 

Installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                      aspnetcore-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                       
  dotnet-apphost-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                     dotnet-host-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                         
  dotnet-hostfxr-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                          dotnet-runtime-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                                  
  dotnet-sdk-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                            dotnet-targeting-pack-7.0-7.0.5-2.el9.aarch64                           
  dotnet-templates-7.0-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                      libicu-67.1-9.el9.aarch64                                               
  lttng-ust-2.12.0-6.el9.aarch64                                  netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-7.0.105-2.el9.aarch64                    
  numactl-libs-2.0.14-7.el9.aarch64                               userspace-rcu-0.12.1-6.el9.aarch64                                      

Complete!
```

Then with

`dotnet --info`

i got this (you can observe the same commit as yours, on the host   **Commit:  8042d61b17**, so this version could be good for you).

```
[root@ebf572389108 .dotnet]# dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.105
 Commit:    e1bc5e001c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     centos
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         centos.9-arm64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/7.0.105/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: arm64
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.105 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [//.dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Anyway, i could guess that in your case the script does not set the right paths.

Note that that the architecture of mine is arm64, different from your AMD64.

However you could try the command `dnf` above.

**Play with docker**

If you use docker you could try to install dotnet in a container (a fresh environment could help), like this:

```
FROM dokken/centos-stream-9
RUN  dnf install dotnet-sdk-7.0 -y
CMD [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
```

build the image:

`docker build -t centos-dot2 .`

run the image:

`docker run --name cent centos-dot2`
after the command the terminal will hang this terminal window (because of `tail`)

Then, from another terminal, enter in the container:

`docker exec -it cent bash`

From here you can run `dotnet --info`

Finally, when you exit from the container with `exit`, stop it and release with:

`docker rm -f cent`

Maybe this is not the answer you were looking for, but anyway

Hope it helps!

Cose belle!

Comment: I had just tried the `dnf install ...` command and that did not work. I have the same results. I'm not sure what else I might need to check.

Comment: I know that could be useless for your use case and i dont want bother you, but, did you tried on a docker container, either?

Comment: No. I have resolved this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Quite by accident, I executed `sudo yum update` and the SDK is showing installed with `dotnet --info`.

> [PatriotRants@Unknown ~]$ dotnet --info .NET SDK:  Version:   7.0.305
> Commit:    98e1b6c381
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     centos  OS Version:  9  OS
> Platform: Linux  RID:         centos.9-x64  Base Path:
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.305/
>
> Host:   Version:      7.0.8   Architecture: x64   Commit:
> 4b0550942d
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 7.0.305 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.8
> [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.8
> [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> Other architectures found:   None
>
> Environment variables:   DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/lib64/dotnet]
>
> global.json file:   Not found
>
> Learn more:   https://aka.ms/dotnet/info
>
> Download .NET:   https://aka.ms/dotnet/download